# Image from Npm package not found in Webpack

Tags: webpack, bxslider

I am trying to use webpack with bxslider package from npm. 
I have already installed all necessary packages. I get below error when I try to build. Seems like it is not able to find the image from the npm package. It does package js file but when I include css file it seem to not locate image file properly.

Error message:

**ERROR in ./src/scss/index.scss
Module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './images/bx_loader.gif' in 'D:\Test'**

Entry file:

```
import '../scss/index.scss';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/util';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/collapse';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/tab';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip';
import 'bxslider/dist/jquery.bxslider.min';
import './main';
```

Webpack config file:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require( 'extract-text-webpack-plugin' );
const theme_path = 'dist/wp-content/themes/theme-name/';
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    app: './src/js/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, theme_path + 'assets/js')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      // Run Sass through loaders before bundling into `style.css`
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract([
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              minimize: true,
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader'
          }
        ])
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('../css/main.css'),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
      Collapse: 'exports-loader?Collapse!bootstrap/js/dist/collapse',
      Dropdown: 'exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown',
      Tab: 'exports-loader?Tab!bootstrap/js/dist/tab',
      Tooltip: "exports-loader?Tooltip!bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip",
      Util: 'exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util'
    })
  ]
};
```